# Image positioning with CSS grid and flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

[what my image gallery is like at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LgCB.jpg)

As you see I have 2 images in the grid system taking up 50% of the width. the problem I have is I want to have a third image below taking up 100% of the width below these two but still in the grid so it downsizes along with the other two images so how can I do this?
the HTML code I have is:

```html
<div class="images">
  <img
    src="protest_2.jpg"
    alt="a protest for black lives matter with their faces blurred"
  />
  <img src="protest_1.jpg" alt="a climate strike with their faces blurred" />
</div>
```

the css code I have is:

```css
.images img {
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.images {
    /* CHANGE TO GRID */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    justify-content: space-between;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    width: 940px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .images {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set `grid-row:` of the first two images to `2` and set it to `3` for the last image. Elements in the same row will align.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the image to span 2 columns, so use `nth-child` to select the third image and use `grid-column-end`:

```
.images img:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
```

Or if you don't want to use `nth-child`, you can add a class to it and select it that way instead.